# angular typescript: translate string literals in templates

Tags: angular, typescript, internationalization, literals

I have the following link:

```
<a (click)="modal.confirm('Do you want exit the system?', exit)" i18n>Sign out</a>
```

And I would like to translate the string 'Do you want exit the system?', but I can't figure out how to achieve it. Is that possible?

I didn't found anything related to this situation in the official documentation:
https://angular.io/guide/i18n

Comment: Actually, I'd say no. 

I remember of someone that found a workaround with viewChilds though : he created HTML tags that contained the sentences to translate, and requested them via a service made for this.

Answer (score 1):

Check https://github.com/ngx-translate/core

If you want it inside the component, you will have to use the **instant** method
The code would be

```
translateService.instant('key');
```

Where key is the string which comes from the locale file

If you want it from the view/tempalte

```
<a (click)="modal.confirm('{{ "key" | translate }}', exit)" i18n>Sign out</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally addressed it this way:

```
<a #signOutLink (click)="modal.confirm(signOutLink.dataset.message, exit)"
  i18n-data-message="@@signOutMessage" data-message="Do you want exit the system?"
  i18n-title="@@signOut" title="Sign out"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i></a>
```

Or, if we do not want to use a redundant data-binding, we can use the following approach:

```
<a (click)="modal.confirm($event.currentTarget.dataset.message, exit)"
  i18n-data-message="@@signOutMessage" data-message="Do you want exit the system?"
  i18n-title="@@signOut" title="Sign out"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i></a>
```

I initialized the `data-message` attribute with a default message and then I used the `i18n-data-message` attribute to translate the message to the corresponding language. And it worked.